# Error inserting multiple rows into sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data in my table but I'm getting error

```
insert into Search_file(
type,
fileName,
document_title_id
)values
(value1,value2,value3),
(value1,value2,value3)

near "values": syntax error:insert into Search_file(
type,
    fileName,
    document_title_id
)values
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: I don't know if that query is intended to be literal, or coming from your code, but it isn't valid as a literal query.  Are `value1`, `value2` etc. supposed to be variables or something?

Comment: The `VALUES` clause generally has to contain literal values, such as `'strings'` and `123` numbers.

Comment: If I want to insert many values, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either insert from values with literal values, or insert from a select.

So it's either something like this:

```
insert into Search_file (type, fileName, document_title_id) values
 ('X','docX', 11111)
,('Y','docY', 22222)
```

Or something like that:

```
insert into Search_file (type, fileName, document_title_id) 
select value1, value2, value3
from sourceTable
where value1 in ('X','Y')
```

And if the destination table doesn't exist yet (or you dropped it beforehand).
Then creating it on the fly from a select is also possible.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_temp_table AS 
SELECT * FROM sourceTable WHERE value1 in ('X','Y')
```